# Linux LiveUSB installer doesn't recognize hard drive or Wi-Fi in new HP laptop

Tags: linux, system-installation

I just bought an HP Notebook 14-dk0002dx laptop ([specs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06429939)). I want to wipe the pre-loaded Windows 10 distribution and install Linux.

I had no trouble booting into Linux from a LiveUSB, but installation ran into two problems. First, the Linux live environments didn't let me connect via Wi-Fi. Network managers only gave Ethernet as a possible Internet connection and didn't mention Wi-Fi at all, though I had no trouble connecting to my home Wi-Fi on Windows.

Second and more seriously, the Linux installers did not seem to recognize that the laptop hard disk exists and could be used for installation. Here's a "screenshot" from Lubuntu, showing that the only disk detected is the LiveUSB itself: [image]

Identical Wi-Fi and installer problems occurred on current versions of several other distros: Debian, Linux Mint Xfce, and Manjaro. It seems that the hard disk problem at least has occurred on other HP computers, but there's a lot of discrepant advice, much of it seemingly outdated, on how to fix it. Is this a well-known problem?

Comment: Also for me Lubuntu's installer Calamares has problems to see an nvme drive. The other light-weight Ubuntu flavour, Xubuntu, has another installer, Ubiquity, and it can see and install into an nvme drive. I did it a couple of weeks ago with **Xubuntu 19.10**. An alternative is **Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS**. I think it has still the Ubiquity installer, and should also work with nvme (but I have not tried it).

Comment: Another problem might be that Windwos is hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias Fast Startup). In this case Ubuntu (or Lubuntu) will stay away from the Windows drive in order to avoid corruption. In this case the quick solution is to reboot Windows (and turn it off directly before it gets into Windows, for example while still in the temporary boot menu. After reboot there is no hibernation or semi-hibernation.

Comment: @sudodus - I did see a mention of Fast Startup in another thread. I'll give that advice a try when I can. Any idea what could be the problem with wifi? And I don't think the problem is with Calamares: distros that used other installers gave the same problem.

Comment: The problem with wifi is probably that there is no linux driver for the wifi chip (the hardware) in your computer. For example Broadcom does not provide information to the linux community to create a free driver. After installation it is possible to installl a proprietary driver. Please tell us about your wifi chip (brand name and model). It can help us help you with more details. Is this correct (according to your link), 'Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n (1x1) and Bluetooth® 4.2 combo'?

Comment: In a fairly new Lenovo laptop I have to go into the UEFI/BIOS menu system and switch 'Storage - Controller Mode' between RST for Windows and AHCI for linux. This or something similar may be relevant for your HP computer.